# Proofreading of ReST in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, restructuredtext

I recently came across [Proofreading tool in PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/proofreading.html).

In `Editor | Proofreading | Grammar` menu, there is a selection of file types for which the proofreading is carried out. However, the list does not contain ReST files.

Is there is way how to force PyCharm to check the ReST files as well (to check the English there)?

My intention is to use it for polishing my Sphinx documentation.

Edit:

[image: My setting in Inspections]

This is my setting in `Inspections`.

[image: My setting in Proofreading]

This is my setting in `Proofreading`.

I use PyCharm Professional 2020.3

Organization of my code is following:

```
main_dir
|- doc
|- code
|- examples
...
```

The ReST files lies in the `doc` directory, while `main_dir` is the root of the PyCharm Project.

Comment: [Link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-46116) to this issue in JetBrains bug tracker.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for this is configuring `Inspections` together with `Proofreading`.

The standard PyCharm configurations should be set to Inspect your Proofreading settings `In All Scopes` regardless of the file type.

Check in `Settings -> Editor -> Inspections -> Proofreading`.

[image: IDE inspection screenshot]

It's not entirely clear from the [JetBrains guide to configure Grammar](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/grammar.html) but there is a possibility reST files may be considered *"Check grammar in embedded code documentation."* Looking at the IDE configuration in the below screenshot:

| Option | Description |
| --- | --- |
| Comments | Check grammar in generic line and block comments. |
| Documentation | Check grammar in embedded code documentation. |

[image: IDE config proofreading screenshot]

**EDIT:** After OP feedback.

The first edit of the question seemed to ask both about typos and grammar. So I tried this again, specifically for grammar proofreading using the example sentence *"This are mistakes."* (should be corrected to *"these are mistakes"*). It works for `.py` files and `.txt` files and PyCharm will suggest a correction but notably with different dialogue windows. Examples as follow:

For `.py` files

[image: image for .py files]

For `.txt` files

[image: image for .txt files]

The usual approach for these cases is creating a [custom scope](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/settings-scopes.html). And so I did trying several combinations like `file:*.rst`, or `file[my_project]:docs/source/*.rst`:

[image: image for custom scope]

Then adding the scope specifically to the grammar proofreading:

[image]

But it still doesn't work for `.rst` files.

For reference, there are [several examples](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206177449-Disable-spelling-checking-inspection-for-specific-file-types-) of this approach under similar circumstances, [this older post](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206179039-Disable-spell-checker-by-file-type-), and [a recent one](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360001330259-Spell-checking-doesn-t-work-in-Markdown-files) by a JetBrains staff member.

I think this is a PyCharm bug that warrants [opening a ticket on the JetBrains bug tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues?q=grammar%20restructuredtext).

Comment: I does not work for me. Still no grammar checking happens for the ReST files, although, I have exactly the same setting as you shown. For example 'This are mistakes.' is correctly highlighted as an error in `.py` and `.ipynb` files (in comment and markdown cell, respectively), but not in `.rst` file. Does it work in your ReST files?

Comment: @TomášHons yes it does work in my ReST files (I just double-checked again). Does the IDE highlight simple typos in your reST files with your current settings? Can you show an example of the *"scope"* you use for your reST files (are they inside an open project)?

Comment: Yes, simple typos are highlighted. That is 'This are mistakes.' triggers no highlight, however, 'Thes are mistakes.' does (as 'Thes' is a typo). For the first line in `.ipynb` I receiving the following 'Did you mean these? Incorrect: This are errors. Correct: These are errors. Powered by LanguageTool'. Does it matched to your problem description in ReST files?

Answer (score 0):

You must enable "Process code" and "Process literals" for rst file scope in Proof reading inspection, see [settings image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXfyW.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).